# storm0.9.3 cluster in local machine

Tags: apache-storm, nimbus

zookeeper installed and runing successfully.but storm nimbus is not running throwing exceptions like below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at backtype.storm.config$loading__4910__auto__.invoke(config.clj:17)
    at backtype.storm.config__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at backtype.storm.config__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2098)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5417)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:621)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5507)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at backtype.storm.command.config_value$loading__4910__auto__.invoke(config_value.clj:16)
    at backtype.storm.command.config_value__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at backtype.storm.command.config_value__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2098)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
    at backtype.storm.command.config_value.<clinit>(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:141)
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:188)
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:71)
    ... 36 more
```

## storm.yamll

storm.zookeeper.servers:"localhost"
 nimbus.host:"localhost"

Comment: can you also post your storm.yaml file form classpath

Answer (score 0):

Made it two liner in your storm.yaml, like below:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:"localhost"
nimbus.host:"localhost"
```

And read about how .yaml syntax used from [here](http://docs.ansible.com/YAMLSyntax.html)